# How can I scan document in Expo?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building the Mobile app with Expo and should implement the document scanner feature.
But I could not find the solution to implement for scanning documents.
I can see only the react-native-document-scanner npm library for React Native, not for Expo.

If anybody has a good solution, Please help me...

Thanks

Comment: Did you got answer

Answer (score 2):

There is no document scanner lib for the expo and seems the expo team has been working for that.
So I switch the project to React Native without expo and now working well.
If we should use the expo, the only way to use 3rd service for scan documentation.
Hope this answer will be updated when the expo has module for that.

Comment: What did you use in React Native?

Answer (score 0):

Hey instead of installing normal react native like Ryan said run npx expo run:android same ios at end and the configuration of document scan lib will work.